# It's possible to record leads analytics about "Source", "Medium" and "Campaign" on a Custom HTML Form?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-analytics

I know that this question is kinda weird but I have a CRM platform integrated with a MySQL database.

In this way, each new row in the MySQL database is a lead in the CRM system but now I need to track all information related with source, ect... from that lead and seems like a complicated task but don't really know if is possible.

I have hours looking for a solution and still haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replicate programmatically what Google Analytics do and save value in cookie or database.

For example, when user lands on website with `UTM` in the URL you can get that values, if there aren't UTM you can check if there is `gclid` parameter in the URL so it will be **google / cpc**, if there isn't that parameter you can check `document referral`, if it is *google.com* your source and medium will be **google / organic**, alternatively ***website* / referral**.

You save the data the first time and pass it in the form. This is the principle makes use of.